# An HTTP/2 connection could not be established because the server did not complete the HTTP/2 handshake

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

I wanted to use a self signed certificate to can use gRPC dotnet, but I get this error when I call the service from my client: An HTTP/2 connection could not be established because the server did not complete the HTTP/2 handshake.

I have created the pfx certificate with this script:

```
@echo off
set path="C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin"
#set OPENSSL_CONF=D:\programas\OpenSSL-Win64\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg   





#CA

echo Generate CA key:
openssl genrsa -passout pass:1111 -des3 -out ca.key 4096

echo Generate CA certificate:
openssl req -passin pass:1111 -new -x509 -days 36500 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -subj  "/C=US/ST=CA/L=Cupertino/O=YourCompany/OU=YourApp/CN=MyRootCA"





#SERVER

echo Generate server key:
openssl genrsa -passout pass:1111 -des3 -out server.key 4096

echo Generate server signing request:
openssl req -passin pass:1111 -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj  "/C=US/ST=CA/L=Cupertino/O=YourCompany/OU=YourApp/CN=%COMPUTERNAME%"

echo Self-sign server certificate:
openssl x509 -req -passin pass:1111 -days 36500 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out server.crt

#Se crea el certificado pfx
openssl pkcs12 -export -out server.pfx -inkey server.key -in server.crt

echo Remove passphrase from server key:
#openssl rsa -passin pass:1111 -in server.key -out server.key





#CLIENT

echo Generate client key
openssl genrsa -passout pass:1111 -des3 -out client.key 4096

echo Generate client signing request:
openssl req -passin pass:1111 -new -key client.key -out client.csr -subj  "/C=US/ST=CA/L=Cupertino/O=YourCompany/OU=YourApp/CN=%CLIENT-COMPUTERNAME%"

echo Self-sign client certificate:
openssl x509 -passin pass:1111 -req -days 36500 -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out client.crt

#Se crea el certificado pfx
openssl pkcs12 -export -out client.pfx -inkey client.key -in client.crt

echo Remove passphrase from client key:
#openssl rsa -passin pass:1111 -in client.key -out client.key












pause
```

In my service, I use this code:

```
            webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5001, listenOptions =>
                {
                    listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
                    listenOptions.UseHttps("server.pfx", "1111");
                    //listenOptions.UseHttps("<path to .pfx file>", "<certificate password>");
                });
            });
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();



            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

In my client I have this code:

```
X509Certificate2 miCertificado = new X509Certificate2("client.pfx", "1111");

HttpClientHandler miHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
miHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(miCertificado);
HttpClient miHttpClient = new HttpClient(miHandler);

GrpcChannelOptions misOpciones = new GrpcChannelOptions() { HttpClient = miHttpClient };

var miChannel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://1.1.1.2:5001");

var miClient = MagicOnionClient.Create<IInterface>(miChannel);

ComponentesDto miDataResultado = await miClient.GetDataAsync();
```

I don't see how it could be the problem. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: `GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://1.1.1.2:5001");` - you mean https?

Comment: If you're wanting to make up examples (I highly doubt that you're actually in the `1.0.0.0/8` network) please use addresses [reserved for documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses)

Comment: I'd also try making http2 request to your endpoint with curl and openssl to check it looks OK, e.g. `curl --http2 -D - https://1.1.1.2:5001`

Comment: I have tried with the IP 192.168.1.134 and I still have the same problem.

Comment: With curl I get this error: curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate.

Comment: True, you need an extra -k for self-signed certificates.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I am currently having the same issue...

Comment: @dan-kli is your client a windows aplication (WPF for example) or is an android application?

Comment: Its a WPF app. I had the same error message and got rid of it by giving the service administration rights. Kinda unintuitive but it somehow resolved the handshake issue, maybe the service had problems accessing the root certificate...

Comment: I will add an ansser now with the solution, but the error it is possible to be related with the way you generate the certificates.

Comment: How did you solve the issue? Yeah could be that I generate my certs wrong, I used a powershell script to generate self-signed certs, idk to much about it..

Comment: @dan-kli I have post a answer that it is possible to solve your problem. If you can't solve it, tell me and I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I already mentioned, I got rid of the error by executing the service from a user account that has admin rights. I created self-signed .pfx certificates, its working now.

Comment: Really it shouldn't need to have administrator right to run the service. I can run my ASP project as normal user and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This question is almost one and half year, and since that, I have done many tries until I could solve my problem.

I don't remember the exact way how I solved the problem, but I will modify this answer if it is needed according to the comments.

My solution is using .NET 6, that is the last stable verstion actually, but I guess that some parts could be work with .NET 5, but keep in mind that this solution is using .NET 6.

One important part in the handshake is the creation of the certificate, and more when it is self signed certificate. My solution works with .crt files instead of the pfx files that I tried to use in my original question.

About the server certificate, one important thing is that it has to have in the SAN the IP of the server, or the URL of the server. You can set both. If you open your .crt file with the notepad for example, you will see something like that:

```
        Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
X509v3 extensions:
    X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
        CA:FALSE
    X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
        44:C4:BD:F
    X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
        keyid:0F:58:2
        DirName:/CN=gRPC-CA
        serial:22:A3
    X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
        TLS Web Server Authentication
    X509v3 Key Usage: 
        Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
    X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
        IP Address:192.168.1.100
```

Signature Algorithm: sha512WithRSAEncryption

In the last 3 lines, you can see that I have in the SAN (Subject Alternative Name), the IP of the server.

To create the certificates, I used easy rsa 3, that it is a tool that make easier to generate self signed certificates. You can find the tool here: https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa and you can download the binaries in the release section: https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa/releases.

The general steps are:

1.- copy the file vars.example in the same folder and call it "vars" (with no exetnsion).
2.- Edit the vars file with the information that you need.
3.- Run EasyRSA-Start.bat to start the shell of easy rsa.
4.- Run easyrsa init-pki to init the evironment. IMPORTANT: only do once, because if not you will delete all the certificates that you could have.
5.- Run easyrsa build-ca to create the CA certificate.
6.- Run easyrsa build-server-full 192.168.1.2 nopass to create the certificate for the server. IMPORTANT: change the IP for the IP of your server.
7.- Run easyrsa build-client-full Cliente01 nopass to create the certificate for the client. IMPORTANT: change the name Cliente01 to the name of your certificate. The name you put here, it will be the common name of the certificate.

All the certificates are created in the subfolder PKI.

I am hosting my service in a ASP application. Using minimal API, in the program.cs file of the ASP project I have to create a X509 certificate in this way:

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
{
    string miStrCertificado = File.ReadAllText("certificados/server.crt");
    string miStrKey = File.ReadAllText("certificados/server.key");
    X509Certificate2 miCertficadoX509 = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(miStrCertificado, miStrKey);

    //it is needed to create a second certificate because if not, you will get an error.
    //Here you can find information about the issue: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/74093
    X509Certificate2 miCertificado2 = new X509Certificate2(miCertficadoX509.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12));

    //For security, delete the first certificate.
    miCertficadoX509.Dispose();


    options.ListenAnyIP(5001, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
        listenOptions.UseHttps(miCertificado2);
    });
});
```

And this is the client of grpc:

```
public async Task<List<FacturasDTO>> MymethodAsync()
{
    try
    {
        //Con certificados
        string miStrCertificado = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"Certificados\Client.crt");
        string miStrClave = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"Certificados\Client.key");
        string miStrCA = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"Certificados\ca.crt");


        X509Certificate2 cert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(miStrCertificado, miStrClave);


        HttpClientHandler miHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        miHttpHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
        miHttpHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
        miHttpHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = ServerCertificateCustomValidation;


        HttpClient httpClient = new(miHttpHandler);

        GrpcChannel channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://20.30.40.50:5001", new GrpcChannelOptions
        {
            HttpClient = httpClient
        });



        var client = channel.CreateGrpcService<IFacturasService>();


        var reply = await client.GetFacturasDTOAsync();



        return reply.Facturas;
    }
    catch (RpcException ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}




/// <summary>
/// This method has to implement the logic that ensure that server certificate is a trust certificate.
/// This is needed because the server certificate is a self signed certificate.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="requestMessage"></param>
/// <param name="paramCertificadoServidor"></param>
/// <param name="chain"></param>
/// <param name="sslErrors"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static bool ServerCertificateCustomValidation(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, X509Certificate2 paramCertificadoServidor, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslErrors)
{
    return true;


    //GetCerHasString devuelve la huella
    //if (paramCertificadoServidor.GetCertHashString() == "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    //{
    //    return true;
    //}
    //else
    //{
    //    return sslErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None;
    //}


    //// It is possible inpect the certificate provided by server
    //Console.WriteLine($"Requested URI: {requestMessage.RequestUri}");
    //Console.WriteLine($"Effective date: {certificate.GetEffectiveDateString()}");
    //Console.WriteLine($"Exp date: {certificate.GetExpirationDateString()}");
    //Console.WriteLine($"Issuer: {certificate.Issuer}");
    //Console.WriteLine($"Subject: {certificate.Subject}");

    //// Based on the custom logic it is possible to decide whether the client considers certificate valid or not
    //Console.WriteLine($"Errors: {sslErrors}");
    //return sslErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None;
}
```

Note that the method ServerCertificateCustomValidation() in the client always return true, it is for testing, but you should to implement the logic to ensure the certificate of the server is a trust certificate. I leave some comment code as example how could it be checked, but it is not tested, so I can't ensure it works or if it is the correct way to do. It is just to have some ideas.

I hope this could solve the problem. If not, leave any comment and I will update the solution.